# Sum Frequency then delete row

Tags: r

I made an example dataframe that represents the amount of events in a specific city with a specific rating.

```
data <- data.frame(country=c("Amsterdam", "Amsterdam", "Amsterdam", "New York", "New York", "London", "London", "Berlin"), 
                       rating=c(0.5, 0.4, 0.6, 0.3, 0.4, 0.8, 0.3, 0.3), 
                       events=c(1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0))
```

What i want is

Delete a city when the sum of events is <1. In other words if there were no events in London and Berlin i want all observations with London and Berlin gone.

In reality i have a huge dataset so just deleting row x, won't be an option.

I've tried;

```
data2 <- aggregate(data$events, by=list(country=data$country), FUN=sum)
```

But this (as expected) aggregates the data and hereby i lose my other predictors and observations.

It'd be great if i can get rid of those cities without losing my other predictor (rating) in the process.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: try `data[with(data, ave(events, country, FUN = function(i)sum(i)) > 0),]`

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can you the `tidyverse` package to filter the data by the sum of events

```
library(tidyverse)
data %>% 
  group_by(country) %>%
  filter(sum(events) > 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

A data.table solution:

```
library(data.table)

data <- as.data.table(data)
data[, .SD[sum(events) > 0], by = country]
     country rating events
1: Amsterdam    0.5      1
2: Amsterdam    0.4      1
3: Amsterdam    0.6      0
4:  New York    0.3      1
5:  New York    0.4      1
```